# Crear una variable indefinida y null en python

Tags: javascript, python

Primeramente tengo un codigo de javascript que elimina los valores undefined, null y 0:

```
const clean = (arr) => arr.reduce((acc, el) => {

if (el) {

    acc.push(el);
}

return acc;

}, [] );

const c = clean([1, undefined, null, 0, 2, 4]);

console.log(c);
```

Entonces necesito saber como puedo pasar este codigo a python y que cumpla la misma función que el codigo de javascript que esta arriba. Saludos

Comment: [Lectura recomendada](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) -en inglés-. Recuerda que es recomendable incluir un [mcve], quiero decir, lo que proporcionas funciona en JS, pero, ¿has intentado algo en Python?

Comment: No existen los valores null ni undefined en Python. Lo más cercano es None

Comment: `mi_lista = [1, None, None, 0, 2, 4]; c = [x for x in mi_lista if x]`

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que no hay un equivalente al `undefined` de JavaScript en Python, para lo demás, entiendo que `filter` sería una opción, al igual que en JavaScrtip.

```
c = [1,None, 0, 2, 4]

res = list(filter(lambda e: e, c))

print(res)
```

Usando `filter` en JavaScrtipt:

```
const c = [1, undefined, null, 0, 2, 4];

const res = c.filter(e=>e);

console.log(res);
```

En ambos casos el argumento de la función es simplemente cada valor del arreglo. Como si hicieramos *if(todo lo que no sea ni false ni null ni 0 ni undefined)*